# Using Kotlin version 1.2+, but still get compiler error about `use`

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

when running the `gradlew build` or `gradlew install` on my kotlin project, the following exception shows up in the console:

> 'use((T) -> R): R' is only available since Kotlin 1.2 and cannot be used in Kotlin 1.1.
>   Requires newer compiler version to be inlined correctly.

information:

- the project is already configured to use Kotlin version `1.2.40`.
- the project seems to compile and run fine when i run it from my IDE (intelliJ)

what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem.

i updated update my Gradle version from `4.4.1` to `4.7` and then i could build my project with Gradle just fine.

if you are using the gradle wrapper, follow these steps:

1. visit the [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/) to find out what the latest version of Gradle is now.
2. in `[project_root]/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, use the latest Gradle version available for the `distributionUrl` property. for example, here is my `gradle-wrapper.properties`, using Gradle version 4.7:

   ```
   #Fri Jun 02 20:20:27 PDT 2017
   distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   distributionPath=wrapper/dists
   zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
   zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Months later, I encountered the same problem with a projet which is not up to date (still Kotlin 1.1.60), which suddenly stopped being compilable.
I resolved it by using the last version of Gradle Kotlin plugin (1.3.0 as I write).